# "This function takes no arguments" error when calling UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm writing a user defined function for an Excel worksheet and having trouble calling it. Every time I try to insert it, the Function Arguments window says "This function takes no arguments". It does, in fact, take arguments.

I can modify it in the formula bar to pass an argument but it still just displays the formula in the cell.

The function worked when I first created it but after saving it and coming back 4 days later it no longer does. I also tried creating a simple test function (below) and the same error occurs so I suspect it's not a problem with the code but with Excel itself.

```
Public Function ReturnRefContents(SourceString As String)

    ReturnRefContents = SourceString

End Function
```

The problem occurs when using both the full path to the function (`=products.xlsm!Module1.ReturnRefContents("Blah")`) and the shorthand version (`=ReturnRefContents("Blah")`)

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you switch to the [formula view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-or-hide-formulas-f7f5ab4e-bf24-4efc-8fc9-0c1b77a5356f) by using CTRL + ` (grave accent).?

Comment: Perhaps the function declaration should define the return type?  i.e. `Public Function ReturnRefContents(SourceString As String) As String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Trust Center settings - I'd disabled all Macros without notification.

To fix:
File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings
Make sure Macro Settings is set to "Disable all macros with notification". Then when you open your document, you'll get an option to enable the content.

You can also go to File > Info > Security Warning and click "Enable all content" to make the spreadsheet a Trusted Document